# Why can't we have two main functions in C language?

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

Can someone explain me what happen internally happens, except that `main` is the start point and we cannot have two start point.

```
int main()
{
   int main()
   {
      return 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Nested functions aren't a part of C.  There's a GCC extension.  Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't legal C code - in C, functions can't be defined inside of one another.

There's no fundamental reason that you *couldn't* do this, but implementing functions like this either complicates the activation record layout and would hurt efficiency (because of considerations like closures) or introduces the potential for memory errors (if you return a pointer to a function inside another function, and the inner function refers to data in the outer function, what happens?)  In the interests of simplicity and efficiency, C just doesn't support this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: s/declared/defined/ You can *declare* a function inside a function *definition*; you can't nest definitions (though gcc supports it as an extension).

Answer (score 2):

Standard C doesn't allow defining a function inside another function. Some compilers support this as an extension, but the names have to be different, otherwise calling a function by its name would be ambiguous.

`main` is the program's entry point. A program has a single entry point, by definition: it's the function that is executed when the program starts (after some initialization), and the program exits when this function returns (after some cleanup).

Answer (score 0):

Because the program must have a starting point. Function that is named as 'main' is the default starting point in C. That's why 'main' as a name is reserved by the C, and you cannot have another function named 'main'.